# Does $\lim f(x+k)-f(x)=0$ imply $f$ is bounded by a function of logarithmic-polynomial type with $0<p<1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Motivation :
The question $\lim \sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x=0$ makes one wonder : if $\lim f(x+k)-f(x)=0$ imply imply $f$ is bounded by a function of logarithmic-polynomial type with $0<p<1$.

It was easy to see (I think) $\lim f(x+k)-f(x)=c$ is some linear function of x , or $x^p$ where $p=1$,

$\lim f(x+k)-f(x)=\infty$ then $f(x)$ is of type $x^p$ for some p>1.

Maybe a better question to ask would be to ask if $\lim f(x+k)-f(x)$ can be used for some type of characterization of $f(x)$?

As this is just an idle musing, not sure if this is already covered under some topic in (real/complex/functional) analysis.

Comment: Note that this is also true for $p=0$, $f=\log$ (since $\log(x+k)-\log(x)=\log(\frac{x+k}{x})\rightarrow \log(1)=1$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$) or even $f(x)=x^p\sin(x)$. Thus the statement might look like 'f is bounded by a function of logarithmic-polynomial type with $0\leq p <1$'.

Comment: @dennis_s : thank you , that is far better elocuted than I could